# Можно ли так переносить: "парикма-хер"?

Tags: орфография, перенос

Можно ли так переносить: "парикма-хер"? Не будет за это двойка?

Comment: Двойка — за сомнения.

Answer (score 2):

Если учительница адекватная, то не будет. А почему такое? Из-за неблагозвучия? Эти вещи правилами русского языка, тем более - школьной программы, не регулируются.
А вот если есть грамматические сомнения, то прошу изложить, какие. Отрыв одной буквы от корня давно перестал быть чем-то наказуемым, ничего более я тут не вижу.